# Efficient way to bulk load SQLite tables with CLOBs into Oracle Database

Tags: database, oracle, sqlite, import, export

I have SQLite database with data that I'd like to push into an Oracle database. Some of the SQLite tables are relatively large, with several hundred thousand rows, so inserting a row at a time from one to the other is painfully slow. I am aware of tools like SQL*Loader for Oracle <strike>, but there are some CLOB tables that I think will cause problems for SQL*Loader (which seems to expect a delimited flat file and some sort of control file).</strike> To make things more complicated, some of the data may exist in the Oracle database, so I'd like it to do a merge rather than an insert.

What is the most efficient way to get the data out of SQLite (besides a CSV, which won't work due to CLOBs) and get it into Oracle? **EDIT**: it seems like SQL*Loader is my best bet getting the data into Oracle, and can indeed handle importing CLOBs in a number of different ways.  Does anybody have any tips for creating the control and data files from a SQLite database?